# How to remove the date field from Drupal 6 inbuilt comment module.

Tags: datetime, drupal, drupal-comments

I want to remove the date field from the comments of Drupal site.
http://agmrcet.com/demo/node/5#comment
I have posted a dummy comment here. Which shows Submitted by admin on Fri, 03/25/2011 - 23:59.
I dont want the date and time stamp to be present. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Edit the `node.tpl.php` of your theme. If you have difficulties finding the right place in the file use the devel themer module and Firebug for Firefox.